# Laravel 8.x - Storing data with Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I've got a `User` model that `hasOne` `Membership` model, with a `users` table and a `memberships` table (each entry in the `memberships` table has a *foreign key* linked to a `user_id`).

I've made a registration page that lets the user have a 7 days trial period on the membership but I'm having trouble storing the data.

This is the `dd()` of the data in the registration form:

```php
"_token" => "ckRlMligEyTwu7ssOi4TmesycbsPpVQlrJ4jQaBd"
"username" => "JaneDoe"
"password" => "password"
"password_confirmation" => "password"
"expiration" => "2021-04-30"
```

Now in my controller I've got the following `store()` method:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    // validating
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => ['required', 'max:200'],
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'expiration' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    // storing
    User::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        'expiration' => $request->expiration
    ]);
}
```

This won't store anything in the `memberships` table and I have no idea how to correctly write the `store` method using the Model's *Eloquent Relationships* declared.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
While trying to make some sense i've modified the `store()` function, now looks like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    // validating
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => ['required', 'max:200'],
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'expiration' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    // storing
    User::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
    ])->membership(Membership::create([
        'expiration' => $request->expiration
    ]));
}
```

Now seems like Laravel doesn't know where to get the `user_id` of the newly created user, like the error suggests:
`` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `memberships` (`expiration`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) ``

Comment: What is the error? you need to post the error here

Comment: It was giving me an error for an unrelated reason, but after correcting it and double checking now it doesn't store anything in the `memberships` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is to do:

```php
User::create([
    'username' => $request->username,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
])->membership()->create([
    'expiration' => $request->expiration
]);
```

Using the relation (`membership()` not `membership` as an attribute) will already know the relation key (`user_id` in this case).

You can see more info about this in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

---

Other way of doing same is:

```php
$membership = new Membership([
    'expiration' => $request->expiration
]);

User::create([
    'username' => $request->username,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
])->membership()->save($membership);
```

More info about [`save()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method).

Comment: I was just writing the answer to my own question and saw the notification. Thank you, i'll take this as a confirmation of a proper way to do it. Hope this helps others

Comment: No problem !!! For anyone seen this, remember you can do the inverse of this (`membership -> user` instead of `user -> membership`) but using other methods, look at the documentation I've shared, the next 2 items is doing the same but for the inverse of the relation (it does not use same methods).